# Reading a grid from file in C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read some data from a text file using C++. However it prints weird numbers on the console.

My input file exactly the same as :

```
3 6
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Then I wrote very simple code just like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc , char* argv[]) {

ifstream fin(argv[1]);

int grid_i;
int grid_j;

fin>>grid_i;
fin>>grid_j;

cout <<grid_i<<endl;
cout <<grid_j<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Then output is:

```
8
1875681984
```

I couldn't find where the mistake is. Can you help me?

Comment: The data symbolizes a matrix. 0 are space. 1 are blocked. I will find the shortest path which starts from the left most to right most. Then I was trying to read the file correctly at first. I will send the nodes of matrix to a queue later.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file was opened succesfully and if it's ready for reading:

```
ifstream fin(argv[1]);
if (!fin.good()) {
    cout << "Couldn't open the file.\n";
    return 1;
}
```

It's also a good idea to always check whether reading operations succeed. `operator>>` returns a reference to the stream, which is convertible to bool, so you can use it like this:

```
if (fin >> grid_i) {
    // read succeeded, use grid_i
}
```

Your program can actually lead to undefined behaviour. When opening a stream (and subsequently, reading from it) fails, `grid_i` and `grid_j` never get initialized/assigned. Reading objects with indeterminate values is undefined behaviour by definition. It's good practice to always initialize your objects

`int grid_i = 0;`

Comment: And you're sure that `fin>>grid_i`, `grid_i` being an integer, makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it does slhck. But it doesnt open the file.. Why not open the file?

Comment: I can't tell you that, I'm afraid. Maybe it isn't located where you think it is, maybe you misytyped the argument to the program, or perhaps the file is opened in another program, etc...

Comment: UB = undefined behavior. Edited the answer, sorry 'bout that :) when you invoke UB, there's absolutely no guarantees (by C++ standard) about how your program should behave. The usual metaphoric answer is that it could make demons fly out of your nose :)